# Avoid auto scrolling to the top after aligning with an anchor properly

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I have one of those issues that I have been staring at and researching, but can't figure out.

I am loading a listing page with a hash: (example URL)

> service_page1.php?u=XX01-TR000016#000016

I have my anchors set: (Example Code)

```
<div class="b_list_normal_row_ws">
  <a name="000013"></a>
  <div class="b_list_row_item_But"><img example />
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently I am testing within Safari (latest version) on a Mac.  When I load the page, it scrolls to the proper spot for the anchor and then scrolls to the top.  I have read other threads about stopping the auto-scroll to the top, but not found one (as of yet) that solves my problem.

Update: I have been working to figure out what could be causing this issue. I have since discovered that if I remove ALL included js files, then the anchors work just fine.  However, if I include even the jquery file, then they stop working.  The search continues...

Comment: can you provide a JSFiddle with your code snippet including CSS and JScript snippet that you have?

Comment: Due to the nature of the project, there isn't much actual code I can share, and that is frustrating on my end also. Pointing in the right direction is wonderful though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon serious amounts of testing, it turns out that Safari (6.0.4) is the cause of the problem.

Tested with different browsers, Safari is the only one that is having the problem with the anchors.

With Safari, there is some form of conflict between javascript and the anchors, though it is out of my control.  I have updated all my scripts to the latest versions also.

**Browsers tested, all the latest possible versions:**
Safari (Windows)
Firefox (Windows)
Chrome (Windows)
IE 9
Firefox (OS X Latest)
Chrome (OS X Latest)
Safari (iOS)
Chrome (iOS)
Safari (OS X Latest)* The problem child

**UPDATE (June 11):**
I have just tested the same site with the new version of OS X and Safari in the public preview and it seems that they fix this issue with the next release.  Hopefully, they don't break it again before then.